# How to redirect user to specific page as Session Expire or abandon

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I just make a Login page with session object. Storing some values in session (userId, userName, UserRoleId). As I know that default time of session is 20 mins. I want that if user watching a page and **as session expiry happen then redirect him to login page**. How it possible is there any event exists which fire **automatically** as specific session expire? so that I write logic there.
I search about global.asax then I use this but it is not working..

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Try this https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Auto-redirect-to-login-e1782b2f

Answer (score 0):

On your master page class :

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
```

On your master page page-load:

```
public Page_Load()
{
if (!page.ispostback)
{

   System.Threading.Timer TimerForSessionExpire = new System.Threading.Timer(TickForSessionExpire, null, 0, 6000*60); // check after every 1 minute
}
else
{
   stopWatch.reset();
   stopWatch.start();
}
}

public void TickForSessionExpire()
{
   if (stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes>20)
   {
       Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
   }
}
```

I have not tested this but logic should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to do it at the client side using javascript. You can call an action which will check the status of your session and then redirect the user by setting a new location for your page.

If you want to drive it from the server, you can use Signalr and a hub. When the session expires, the hub call the client (still in js) and you will perform the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1205; url=http://domain/login.aspx">` to all your responses.

This redirect the page at 20 min plus 5 seconds to login.aspx.